# Preserve whitespace when using xinclude with docbook

Tags: whitespace, docbook, xinclude

I use **docbook** to generate documents. The structure of the main document is modular using **xinclude** for the different modules.

My problem is about verbatim elements(elements with significant whitespaces) which are included into the main document via xinclude.

If I use a **literallayout** directly in the main document, the output is as expected: whitespaces are preserved.

I want to use an included file which contains a section with a literallayout element.
If I generate a document with the included file the output gets stripped of its whitespaces.

Can anyone tell me how to keep the whitespaces in verbatim elements like literallayout or programlisting?

File1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE section PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<section id="someid">
<title>section title</title>
<para>
<literallayout>
This shall show a small picure with '0':
   0
  000
 00000 
</literallayout>
</para>
</section>
```

If I generate it as standalone document the output is as expected:

```
    0
   000
  00000
```

If I use it as follows:
File2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
<bookinfo>
   ...minimum input here
</bookinfo>
<chapter id="First_Chapter">
    <title>Introduction</title>

    <section id="First_Section">
      <title>literallayout and programlisting in the main xml file</title>

      <para><literallayout>This should look like a triangle built out of the character '0'
   0
  000
 00000
</para>
    </section>

    <xi:include href="File1.xml"
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" />
  </chapter>
</book>
```

If I generate this document the first section will be as expected (as a pyramid)

but in the section which is included with xinclude all '0' are output on one line 0 000 00000.

Comment: *"If I use this code with xinclude..."*. Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you do this.

Comment: What toolchain do you use to process the included content?

Comment: I use Saxon 9 and then fop with the docbook templates.

Answer (score 1):

### **Probable solution**

I think found a solution to the problem myself:
It should help if the included literallayout elements have the attribute **`xml:space="preserve"`** added. This should be the default but it seems that the xinclude somehow "loses" or "replaces" it.

Comment: It seems reasonable that XInclude processing strips whitespace by default. The XInclude processor cannot know where whitespace is significant unless it is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to add CSS styling to the HTML that Docbook outputs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook/modes"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Use Docbook from online content delivery network -->
    <xsl:import href="https://cdn.docbook.org/release/xsltng/current/xslt/docbook.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="docbook-xsltng-base" select="'https://cdn.docbook.org/release/xsltng/current'"/>
    <xsl:param name="resource-base-uri"   select="concat($docbook-xsltng-base, '/resources/')"/>

    <!-- Some CSS customizations -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="m:html-head-last">
        <style type="text/css">
            pre.literallayout {
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                background: #D0E0FF;
                padding: 1em;
                border-radius: 0.5em;
                line-height: normal;
                font-size: smaller;
                font-family: var(--mono-family);
            }
        </style>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The `m:html-head-last` mode is described [here](https://xsltng.docbook.org/guide/m_html-head-last.html) and is one of many points of customization.